# How to convert from javascript form action to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a code javascript of a action form:

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" id="type" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And javascript:

```
function OnSubmitForm() {
    var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
    if(type == '1') {
        document.myform.action = "index.php?type=1";
    }
    if(type == '2') {
        document.myform.action = "index.php?type=2";
    }
    return false;
}
```

How to convert this javascript to jquery, please this ideas?

Comment: jQuery ***is*** Javascript. What do want? `.prop('action', 'index.php?type=1')` maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("form[name='myform']").submit(function() {
    this.action = "index.php?type=" + this.type.value;
    return false;
});
```

- `form[name='myForm']` selects a form with the name `myForm`.
- Calling `.submit(function () { ... })` binds an event handler for the `submit` event.
- Inside the function, `this` refers to the form.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4SZrH/ (check out the form `action` in Firebug or similar).

Comment: I noticed that myform was the name and not id thanks to your answer, so +1

Answer (score 1):

First note that this function **always** returns false, so your form will never submit.  But to answer your question, you could use jQuery's `submit` event

```
$("form[name='myform']").submit(function(){
    var type = this.type.value;
    if (type === '1' || type === '2')
        this.action = "index.php?type=" + type;

    return false;
});
```

Or more simply:

```
$("#myForm").submit(OnSubmitForm);
```

Also note that, for dom level 0 event handlers, you *don't* want the return statement inline.  In the future just do

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="OnSubmitForm();"
```

And let `OnSubmitForm` return true or false

Finally, note that in JavaScript, functions starting with a capital letter by convention denote a **constructor**.  Consider renaming this function to `onSubmitForm`